# Select multiple ORMed objects from subquery

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given this `FromClause`:

```
q = (
    select([Review, Photo])
    .select_from(
        outerjoin(Review, Photo, false())
    ).apply_labels()
).union_all(
    select([Review, Photo])
    .select_from(
        outerjoin(Photo, Review, false())
    ).apply_labels()
)
```

I can select orm objects from it with:

```
s.query(Review, Photo).select_entity_from(q).all()
```

Giving a result of:

```
[(Review(id=1, thing_id=100, ...), None),
 (Review(id=2, thing_id=100, ...), None),
 (Review(id=3, thing_id=101, ...), None),
 (None,                            Photo(id=1, thing_id=100))]
```

I want to join this to my `Thing` table to give:

```
[(Thing(100), Review(id=1, thing_id=100, ...), None),
 (Thing(100), Review(id=2, thing_id=100, ...), None),
 (Thing(101), Review(id=3, thing_id=101, ...), None),
 (Thing(100), None,                            Photo(id=1, thing_id=100)),
 (Thing(102), None,                            None)]
```

### Attempt 1: select_from

However, when I try:

```
thing_q = select([Thing, Review, Photo]).select_from(
    outerjoin(Thing, q,
        (Review.thing_id == Thing.id) |
        (Photo.thing_id == Thing.id)
    )
)
```

The query emitted is:

```sql
SELECT
    things.id, things....,
    -- this should be selecting these from the subquery...
    reviews.id, reviews.thing_id, reviews....,
    photos.id, photos.thing_id, photos....,
FROM
    reviews, -- not from the tables, doing a CROSS JOIN!
    photos,  -- Look, another CROSS JOIN!
    things
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            reviews.id AS reviews_id,
            reviews.thing_id AS reviews_thing_id,
            reviews.... as reviews_...,
            photos.id AS photos_id,
            photos.thing_id AS photos_thing_id
            photos.... as photos...,
        FROM
            reviews
            LEFT OUTER JOIN photos ON 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            reviews.id AS reviews_id,
            reviews.thing_id AS reviews_thing_id,
            reviews.... as reviews_...,
            photos.id AS photos_id,
            photos.thing_id AS photos_thing_id
            photos.... as photos...,
        FROM
            photos
            LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews ON 0
    ) ON reviews.thing_id = things.id OR photos.thing_id = things.id
```

Which has done a cross join! How do I go about selecting `Review` and `Photo` from the `UNION ALL` from clause?

### Attempt 2: select_entity_from

```
thing_q = s.query(Thing, Review, Photo).select_entity_from(
    outerjoin(Thing, q,
        (Review.thing_id == Thing.id) |
        (Photo.thing_id == Thing.id)
    )
)
```

Which gives:

```
  File "...\sqlalchemy\lib\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 1397, in visit
    translate_dict[right.element.left] = selectable_
AttributeError: 'CompoundSelect' object has no attribute 'left'
```

Yay, cryptic errors. Not sure what I've done wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`Query.add_entity()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.add_entity) since it would place the `Thing` at the rightmost. Below snippet will works for you maybe:

```
>>> query = session.query(Review, Photo).select_entity_from(q)
>>> query = query.add_entity(Thing)
>>> query = query.join(Thing,
...                    (Thing.id == Review.thing_id) |
...                    (Thing.id == Photo.thing_id))
>>> print query.first()  # Just an expectation...
(Review(id=1, thing_id=100, ...), None, Thing(100))
```